# BeautifulSoup giving different results on server and laptop

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have a piece of code running on server (Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS) and a laptop (Ubuntu 15.04), which is giving different result.
I am building the soup using the same html file (copied it myself to server)

```
temp = open('temp.html', 'r')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(temp.read())
table = soup.find('table')
if not table:
    return []
rows = table.find_all('tr')
print len(rows)
```

Server prints: `2`
whereas locally it prints: `7`

More information:

Server:

- Python 2.7.6
- beautifulsoup4 4.3.2
- pip 7.0.3

Local:

- Python 2.7.9
- beautifulsoup4 4.3.2
- pip 1.5.6

What am I missing? What more things should I look for?

Comment: Do you have `lxml` installed on one and not the other? Does `bs4.BeautifulSoup(temp, 'html.parser')` make the numbers fit?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks, that explains the issue, I didnt have lxml on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My server didn't had lxml installed while lxml 3.4.4 was installed locally. Installing it on the server solved the issue